# Share Extension not working when I long press a link

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

I've built a sharing extension for my iOS app. The goal is to store all URLs user shared in UserDefaults variable. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices

class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as! NSExtensionItem
        let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments?.first as! NSItemProvider
        let propertyList = String(kUTTypePropertyList)
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(propertyList) {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: propertyList, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) -> Void in
                guard let dictionary = item as? NSDictionary else { return }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    if let results = dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey] as? NSDictionary,
                        let urlString = results["URL"] as? String,
                        let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                        print("URL retrieved: \(urlString)")
                        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.my.app")
                        if userDefaults?.object(forKey: "extensionArticles") == nil {
                            userDefaults?.setValue([urlString], forKey: "extensionArticles")
                        } else {
                            var urls = userDefaults?.object(forKey: "extensionArticles") as? [String]
                            urls?.append(urlString)
                            print("im here in the extension")
                            dump(urls)
                            userDefaults?.setValue(urls, forKey: "extensionArticles")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.didSelectPost), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
    
    

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return true
    }

    override func didSelectPost() {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
    print("posted")
        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
        
        
     
        
    }

    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
        return []
    }

}
```

When I go to the webpage in Safari and share it being on that page, everything works fine. However, when I long press (aka 3d touch) on a link in Safari, and use my extension from there, it won't add a link to UserDefaults. I couldn't find how to fix this, plz help

Comment: yeah have the same issue